# My mutations aren't working! How do I correct this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to set the `breakfastMenu` array in `state` as shown below but I can't see the array being filled in my vue-devtools.

I have properly set-up the Vuex methods and checked twice, also I didn't receive any sort of error. So, why do I have a logical error in my code?

`store.js`:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    menu: [],
    breakfastMenu: [],
    lunchMenu: [],
    dinnerMenu: []
  },
  mutations: {
    'SET_MENU': (state, menuMaster) => {
      state.menu = menuMaster;
    },
    'SET_BREAKFAST_MENU': (state, order) => {
      state.breakfastMenu.unshift(order);
    },
    'SET_LUNCH_MENU': (state, order) => {
      state.breakfastMenu.unshift(order);
    },
    'SET_DINNER_MENU': (state, order) => {
      state.breakfastMenu.unshift(order);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    initMenu: ({ commit }, menuMaster) => {
      commit('SET_MENU', menuMaster)
    },
    initBreakfastMenu: ({ commit, state }) => {
      state.menu.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.categoryId == 1) {
          commit('SET_BREAKFAST_MENU', element)
        }
      });
    },
    initLunchMenu: ({ commit, state }) => {
      state.menu.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.categoryId == 2) {
          commit('SET_LUNCH_MENU', element)
        }
      });
    },
    initDinnerMenu: ({ commit, state }) => {
      state.menu.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.categoryId == 3) {
          commit('SET_DINNER_MENU', element)
        }
      });
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getBreakfastMenu(state) {
      return state.breakfastMenu
    },
    getLunchMenu(state) {
      return state.lunchMenu
    },
    getDinnerMenu(state) {
      return state.dinnerMenu
    },
  }
})
```

`Breakfast.vue`:

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      breakfastArray: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['initBreakfastMenu']),
    ...mapGetters(['getBreakfastMenu']),
  },
  created() {
    this.initBreakfastMenu;
    this.breakfastArray = this.getBreakfastMenu;
  }
};
```

No error messages so far!

I need the `breakfastMenu` array filled in `store.js`.

Please help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts.

Firstly, this line:

```js
this.initBreakfastMenu;
```

You aren't actually calling the method. It should be:

```js
this.initBreakfastMenu();
```

Next problem is this:

```js
...mapGetters(['getBreakfastMenu']),
```

The line itself is fine but it's inside your `methods`. It should be in the `computed` section.

You haven't included any sample data for `state.menu` but it's also worth noting that `initBreakfastMenu` won't do anything unless there is suitable data inside `state.menu`. I suggest adding some console logging to ensure that everything is working as expected there.

`SET_BREAKFAST_MENU`, `SET_LUNCH_MENU` and `SET_DINNER_MENU` are all modifying `state.breakfastMenu`. I would assume that this is incorrect and each should be modifying their respective menu.

I would also note that using local data for `breakfastArray` is suspicious. Generally you'd just want to use the store state directly via the computed property rather than referencing it via local `data`. This is not necessarily wrong, you may want to detach the component data from the store in this way, but keep in mind that both are referencing the same array so modification to one will also affect the other. You aren't taking a copy of the array, you're just creating a local reference to it.

You should also consider whether you actually need the 4 menu types within your `state`. If `breakfastMenu`, `lunchMenu` and `dinnerMenu` are all just derived from `menu` then you'd be better off just implementing those using `getters`. `getters` are the store equivalent of computed properties and can contain the relevant filtering logic to generate their value from `state.menu`.

Comment: Dude, you are the best! Thanks for the additional info, it really helped me, also I reduced the number of line of code considerably! As you told me to use getters as filters to fetch breakfast menu... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`initBreakfastMenu` is an action and you may want to use `this.initBreakfastMenu()`

Comment: Thanks soo much, so little issue but takes a lot of time to figure out for a beginner!